# What is the probability that the second customer arrives at least $k$ times faster than the previous one?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-process, exponential-distribution

The exact question is not quite the same (it was hard to put in a concise title) but has the same principle:

The time between customers has an exponential distribution. What is the probability that $T_1$, the time between opening the shop and the first customer, is larger than $k$ times $T_2$, the time between the first and second customer?

In other words, what is $P(T_1>kT_2)$?

This is what I have so far:

- $T_1 > kT_2 \iff T_1+T_2 > (k+1)T_2$
- $T_1$ and $T_2$ have the exponential distribution $f_{T_i}(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$
- $T := T_1+T_2$ has gamma distribution $f_{T}(t) = \frac{\lambda^2}{2}te^{-\lambda t}$.

I don't know how to proceed now. I don't know how to convert $P(T_1>kT_2)$ to something where I can use the distribution functions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume $T_1, T_2$ are independent exponential with parameter $\lambda$. You should indeed start with $P[T_1>kT_2]$, but then you should condition, say, on the value $T_2=t$, and use the law of total probability (in integral form) to consider all possible values of $t$. Or you can condition on $T_1$ if you like.  The overall idea is that conditioning is useful for simplifying a difficult problem.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the help. I calculated $\int_0^\infty P(T_1>kT_2|T_2=t)P(T_2=t)\text{dt} = \int_0^\infty P(T_1>kt)f_{T_2}(t)\text{dt} = \int_0^\infty(\int_{kt}^\infty f_{T_1}(u)du)f_{T_2}(t)dt$ and this gave the result $\dfrac{1}{1+k}$. Could this be correct?

Comment: @Surzilla Your calculation seems fine with me.

Comment: @Surzilla : $P[T_2=t]=0$ so the integral you give in the first line would (strictly speaking) be zero.  Nevertheless your second line fixes the issue correctly.  The law of total probability in integral form for an event $A$ is $$P[A] = \int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty} P[A|X=t]f_X(t)dt \approx \sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} P\left[A|X \in [i\delta, (i+1)\delta)\right]P\left[X \in [i\delta, (i+1)\delta)\right]$$ (for small $\delta>0$).  So $$f_X(t)\delta  \approx P\left[X \in [t, t+\delta)\right]$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of the exponential distribution,
$$
\mathbb P(T_1>t)=\mathbb P(T_2>t)=e^{-\lambda t},\qquad t\geq 0.
$$
Thus,
$$
\mathbb P(T_1>kT_2)=\mathbb E\bigl[\mathbb P(T_1>kT_2\mid T_2)\bigr]=\mathbb Ee^{-\lambda k T_2}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda k x}\cdot \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx,
$$
where in the last line we are integrating against the distribution function. Performing the integral yields
$$
\mathbb P(T_1>kT_2)=\left[\frac{e^{-\lambda(k+1)x}}{k+1}\right]_0^{\infty}=\frac{1}{k+1},
$$
as desired.